# Which API is really depreciated ActivityRecognitionApi or ActivityRecognitionClient

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, activity-recognition, google-location-services

According to Google **[Google APIs for Android](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionApi)** the **ActivityRecognitionApi** interface is deprecated and need to use the **ActivityRecognitionClient** interface. But other **[sources](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/activity-recognition-using-new-googleapiclient-activityrecognitionclient-is-deprecated-in-december-2014/)** saying that the **ActivityRecognitionClient** is depricated and need to use the 
**ActivityRecognitionApi** interface insted.  I am confused :(

And many other **[samples](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/activity-recognition-using-new-googleapiclient-activityrecognitionclient-is-deprecated-in-december-2014/)** on the internet is using the  **ActivityRecognitionApi** interface.

And when we using the **ActivityRecognitionClient** interface the periodic update is not getting only the initial time we will get the update , But he 
**ActivityRecognitionApi** interface update is getting properly.

Which one we need to use ? , If we need to uses **ActivityRecognitionClient** kindly provide a sample code of working Application/Code .

Comment: Official source says A, random other source says B. You're asking which one to trust?

Comment: @TimCastelijns , I think i should trust Google but i used the new interface and there is no periodic update and i am searching for code using new interface.And when i used the old interface the periodic update id getting properly.

Comment: that's not relevant - you're asking which of the 2 is actually deprecated

Comment: I think it is also relevent :) , Thats why i asked for sample code using ActivityRecognitionClient

Comment: Wow i din'nt know that there is no sample code and code solutions are providing from stack overflow . I think you just read my subject line and dont read my full question

Comment: If the question you put in the title does not reflect what you are actually asking then obviously you didn't provide a good title. That's not my fault

Comment: If you not fully read my question and hanging on the subject line ,  then its not my fault

Comment: Two years later.  This is the hardest android function I've tried to program so far.  I get absolutely no results using 4 different tutorials out there. Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: Yes , ActivityRecognitionClient is working well . Tested in device and emulator . The gps need to enable for getting the periodic updates.Tested the device with in a running car and the status is displayed properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 11.8.0 of play services ,`ActivityRecognitionApi` is deprecated.
You should use the new interface , So when the next version comes, you don't have the risk to forcefully update it to the new interface.

Comment: Yes i already  mentioned that according to Google Google APIs for Android the ActivityRecognitionApi is depricated , i used the new interface and there is no periodic update and i am searching for code using new interface